# In SQL, if there is no search parameter, how to not search

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### Overview

In SQL, if there is no search parameter, how to not search

### Detail

I have created a search scope for my model.
searching using the parameters received from the controller.
The problem is if this parameter is blank (null?),search with that blank, and the search result will be 0.
Therefore, if it is blank (null), I want to pass the search process without moving the search.

### Code

item.rb

```
  scope :name_and_id_search_in_items_or_masters, -> (search_name,search_id){
    where(ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize_sql_array(["
        items.status != 1
        AND items.name LIKE :asset_name
        AND items_industries.id = :industry_id
      OR items.status = 1
        AND masters.name LIKE :asset_name
        AND masters_industries.id = :industry_id",
        { asset_name: "%#{search_name}%", industry_id: "#{search_id}" }
    ]))
  }
```

items_controller.rb

```
@items = @items.name_and_id_search_in_items_or_masters(index_search_params[:search_name],index_search_params[:search_id])
```

### Environment

Rails 6.0

Comment: Then don't use the scope unless the parameter is supplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since scopes may be concatenated, you need what I call a null query, so that the chain of scopes doesn't break when the params are nil.

From your question it looks as if you are already calling concatenating this scope (`@items = @items.name_and_id_....`)

when a query becomes this complex, a class method is generally preferred. A scope is just another way of writing class method that returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` anyway.

So I've written it here as a class method, but you can do the same thing in a scope.

```rb
def self.name_and_id_search_in_items_or_masters(search_name,search_id)
  return where("1=0") if search_name.nil? || search_id.nil?

  where(ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize_sql_array(["
      items.status != 1
      AND items.name LIKE :asset_name
      AND items_industries.id = :industry_id
    OR items.status = 1
      AND masters.name LIKE :asset_name
      AND masters_industries.id = :industry_id",
      { asset_name: "%#{search_name}%", industry_id: "#{search_id}" }
    ]))
end
```

Comment: Thanks.This solved it. return where("1=1") if search_name.blank? && search_id.blank?